# Contents-check: Data type and its value validation in C++

Tags: c++, types

My data type could be U1, U2, U4, I1, I2, I4 , `std::string` or `bool`.

Assume the data is stored in a `std::vector`.

How can I check the data type by its value?

As far as I know, there is `tryParse()` in C#. How could I do it in C++?

```
Value = MyVec[0]; // the value is 65;
```

I want to validate that the `65` is of type U2 or not?

Comment: What is the exact declaration of the `std::vector` the data are stored in?

Comment: You could look for the ascii value of the value. This way you can differentiate between numeric and non numeric data types. Further you can determine the size of the type for determining what type it is (not perfect though) or process the numeric value with standard numeric ranges for determining a probably type for that value. Also looking at the tryParse() function, it seems that for using that you need to know what type you are trying to parse or try for each probable data type for the value.